# Image links broken while using Routes

Tags: visual-studio-2012, routes

I'm using routes to camo the url address for search engines purpose, so I have added this line in my **Global.asax** (VS2012) file, and the route works as expected:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("shop","it/{id}/{action}.aspx","~/shop.aspx");
```

the problem is that my **shop.aspx** page has some `<img` tags with relative url to images, of course the problem is that the webpage try to lookup the images in the mapped url and no from the real url the page **shop.aspx** is in.

I have also tried to add another route to counter the previous for files under the image folder, I have also added an ignore route, then I tried adding a map of the mapped url:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("logo", "it/{id}/images/logo/", "images/logo/");
```

still no solution to the problem, only way seems to use a `<asp:image` control os use the css, but this would work better for background images, I must use a `<img` tag on my **shop.aspx** page, i cannot put everything on css or controls just for this.

Comment: adding the following lines has no effect:
    routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*allpng}", new { allpng = @".*\.png(/.*)?" });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to google I have resolved with this, however I feel it should be done at routing level instead:

```
<%= ResolveUrl("~/App_Themes/default/images/logo/fb1.png") %>
```